# C++, using stack.h read a string, then display it in reverse

Tags: c++, string, header, stack

For my current assignment, I have to use the following header file,

```
#ifndef STACK_H
#define STACK_H

template <class T, int n>
class STACK
{
  private:
    T a[n];
    int counter;

  public:
    void MakeStack() {
        counter = 0;
    }

    bool FullStack() {
        return (counter == n) ? true : false ;
    }

    bool EmptyStack() {
        return (counter == 0) ? true : false ;
    }

    void PushStack(T x) {
        a[counter] = x;
        counter++;
    }

    T PopStack() {
        counter--;
        return a[counter];
    }
};

#endif
```

To write a program that will take a sentence, store it into the "stack", and then display it in reverse, and I have to allow the user to repeat this process as much as they want. The thing is, I am NOT allowed to use arrays (otherwise I wouldn't need help with this), and am finding myself stumped.

To give an idea of what I am attempting, here is my code as of posting, which obviously does not work fully but is simply meant to give an idea of the assignment.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <ctime>
#include "STACK.h"
using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
    auto time_t a;
    auto STACK<char, 256> s;
    auto string curStr;
    auto int i;

    // Displays the current time and date
    time(&a);
    cout << "Today is " << ctime(&a) << endl;

    s.MakeStack();
    cin >> curStr;
    i = 0;
    do
    {
        s.PushStack(curStr[i]);
        i++;
    } while (s.FullStack() == false);

    do
    {
        cout << s.PopStack();
    } while (s.EmptyStack() == false);

    return 0;
} // end of "main"
```

**UPDATE**
This is my code currently

```
#include   <iostream>
#include   <string>
#include   <ctime>
#include   "STACK.h"
using namespace std;

time_t                      a;
STACK<char, 256>        s;
string             curStr;
int                     i;
int                     n;

// Displays the current time and date
time(&a);
cout << "Today is " << ctime(&a) << endl;

s.MakeStack();
getline(cin, curStr);
i = 0;
n = curStr.size();
do
{
   s.PushStack(curStr[i++]);
    i++;
}while(i < n);

do
{
    cout << s.PopStack();
}while( !(s.EmptyStack()) );    

return 0;
```

Comment: I believe you're on the right track. Since a stack is last-in-first-out, the reversal can be done with relative ease... (PS that code can be simplified quite a bit)

Comment: I have to say, that's the ugliest stack implementation i've seen in a while.  Why are they making you use this crap when there's a perfectly good `std::stack`?

Comment: What is your problem? I mean, beyond pushing _way_ more than the actual string (hint: you forgot to check for the string end).

Comment: By the way, expressions like `(counter == n) ? true : false` can be simplified to only `(counter == n)`.

Comment: And about your use of `auto`, the use of the `auto` keyword has been changed in the latest C++ standard, and it shouldn't be used that way any more. Besides, not using `auto` when you declare a variable in the old version of C++ (and in C) actually implies `auto`; It's the "automatic" storage specifier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're on the right track, but you shouldn't be looping until the stack is *full* -- there are no guarantees `curStr` consists of at least 256 characters. Instead, loop like as follows...

```
int n = curStr.size();
do {
  s.PushStack(curStr[i++]);
} while (i < n);
```

Now, you should really not write `<bool-expr> == false` or `<bool-expr> == true`... instead, merely write `!<bool-expr>` and `<bool-expr>`, respectively. You don't need all of your `auto` storage specifiers on the local variables, either. Your professor should also look into using the constructor rather than using `MakeStack`.

edit: It appears you had some trouble translating my code. You only need to `i++` once per loop -- this increments our position in the string. As you are doing it now, you are actually incrementing the position twice and thus only pushing every other character.

Comment: As a standalone loop, that is just begging for `curStr.size() == 0`.

Comment: The use of auto is an old habit that my old C and C++ teacher made me use. Anyway, using the code you showed it is working closer to what it should be, just the problem is it will only show two characters when it writes itself out in reverse. So when I enter "This is a test", I get back "iT", strangely.

Comment: @user1675108 `cin.operator>>` only reads a single word... but that doesn't explain the missing characters.

Comment: @pickypg you're right, but I wasn't sure if he had done it purposefully so I tried to avoid modifying the behavior much.

Comment: I figured. @user1675108 `auto` now means something else entirely in C++11, so you should get out of that habit.

Comment: @user1675108 it [appears](http://ideone.com/RJqR1#view_edit_box) to be working fine for a single word. If you want an entire line, try `getline`.

Comment: I almost got it working, except on the read back it only displays every other character. For instance, when I type in "This is at test", it writes out "stas iT".

Comment: @user1675108 sounds like you're incrementing/decrementing one too many times per loop. Can you upload the exact code you're using? Use [pastie](http://pastie.org).

Comment: @user1675108 you only need to `i++` once per loop... look at my post again. You're *making* it skip every other character.

Comment: Thanks, I foolishly didn't think to look closer at my loop and realize I had an extra increment. I kept looking at the loop containing PopStack when it was in the first loop all along. It's work now.

Comment: @user1675108 glad I could help :-) make sure to accept the answer which helped you most.

Comment: @oldrinb: it would be mildly more idiomatic to put the `i++` in the `while(...)`.

Comment: @sixlettervariables if you mean putting `++i` in the `while`, yes, I agree.

Comment: @oldrinb: err yep, I'll avoid coding after being on the clock for 12 hours...how about that :)

Answer (score 0):

Use a [`linked list`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list) instead of `array` in stack.

In the linked list, always store the tail pointer of your list's last node. Each node maintains a reference to your prev node.

```
A <--- B <---- C (tail)
```

push:

```
A <--- B <---- C <---- D (tail)
```

pop:

```
A <--- B <---- C (tail)

// D is popped out
```

when the `tail == null`, you know it is an empty stack